# Proper way to inflate custom AlertDialog view within a DialogFragment in API 21 and above

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

Android Studio referred me to https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/ for information about the layout inflate process and how to fix the "avoid passing null as the root view" warnings.

The recommendation is to always pass a valid parent to inflate(), with a famous exception being AlertDialogs with custom views, as the "parent" is not available at the time we call AlertDialog.Builder.setView().

Since API 21 there's a second implementation of AlertDialog.Builder.setView() available, which enables us to pass a layout id instead of a manually inflated layout. The problem is that you cannot access layout members by calling findViewById() on the AlertDialog created by AlertDialog.Builder.create(). findViewById() always returns null, until you manually call AlertDialog.create() on the dialog returned by the builder. That seems to work, but I'm unsure about the implications. Will create() get called multiple times (manually by myself, and later on by the DialogFragment)? Am I causing duplicate initialization work that will have a negative impact on performance and/or memory usage?

Basically, what is the recommended way of inflating custom AlertDialog layouts within DialogFragment.onCreateDialog() since API 21, when you need to access the members of the custom layout before finally showing the dialog to the user?

a)

```
View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_id, null);
AlertDialog ad = (new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()))
    .setView(v)
    .create();
v.findViewById(R.id.view_id).doSomething();
```

b)

```
AlertDialog ad = (new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()))
    .setView(R.layout.layout_id)
    .create();
ad.create();
ad.findViewById(R.id.view_id).doSomething();
```

Comment: This also applies to the support library I think. Did you reach any conclusions on this?